# Overriding django admin get_queryset()

Tags: python, django, django-models, inheritance, django-admin

I have two models which is one of them proxy model.
In admin I registered both and overrided `get_queryset()` method but it is not working as expected.
**admin.py**

```py
@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(language='en')

@admin.register(ProxyCategory)
class ProxyCategoryAdmin(CategoryAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(language='zh')
```

In admin page *ProxyCateegoryAdmin* not showing objects, if I remove `get_queryset()` from *CategoryAdmin*, it works but wanted filter both of them.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This setup with proxies and inheriting existing admin class looks weird to me, but you can simply try debugging the queryset: `print(qs.query)` and see what Django produces (if anything)?

Comment: Everything works here, just ProxyCategoryAdmin returns nothing it works only if I remove get_queryset() method from parent model.

Comment: What do you mean by `returns nothing`? You mean no results on the page? Did you try debugging the `qs` from my suggestion? I.e. set a breakpoint before last return and check how this qs is shaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `self.model` in the `get_queryset` method to filter the correct model.

```
@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if self.model == Category:
            return qs.filter(language='en')
        return qs

@admin.register(ProxyCategory)
class ProxyCategoryAdmin(CategoryAdmin):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want ProxyCategoryAdmin to return both languages, do this:

```
@admin.register(ProxyCategory)
class ProxyCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(language_in=['zh','en'])
```

When you inherit the CategoryAdmin, you end up with 2 filters: EN and ZH instead of EN or ZH

Comment: No, In my case ProxyCategoryAdmin is returning nothing, it works only if I remove `get_queryset()` method from parent model